# Hold and validate an EAN13 code

Tags: java, validation

I've created a class that holds an EAN13 code. This class is an attribute of the `Product` class.

In the `Ean13` class, the `string` that represents the EAN code is passed as a parameter to the constructor and the validation is performed in the constructor. I created some utility methods in that class, like `sumEven`, `sumOdd`, and `isOdd`, but I'm not sure if would be better to move it to a separated utility class.

```
@Embeddable
public class Ean13 {
    private static final RuntimeException NOT_VALID_EAN_EXCEPTION = new RuntimeException("NOT VALID EAN CODE");

    @Column(name = "ean_code", nullable = true, length = 13)
    private String code;

    public Ean13() {
    }

    public Ean13(String code) {
        validate(code);
        this.code = code;
    }

    private void validate(String code) {
        if (code == null || code.length() != 13) {
            throw NOT_VALID_EAN_EXCEPTION;
        }
        if (!CharMatcher.DIGIT.matchesAllOf(code)) {
            throw NOT_VALID_EAN_EXCEPTION;
        }
        String codeWithoutVd = code.substring(0, 12);
        int pretendVd = Integer.valueOf(code.substring(12, 13));
        int e = sumEven(codeWithoutVd);
        int o = sumOdd(codeWithoutVd);
        int me = o * 3;
        int s = me + e;
        int dv = getEanVd(s);
        if (!(pretendVd == dv)) {
            throw NOT_VALID_EAN_EXCEPTION;
        }
    }

    private int getEanVd(int s) {
        return 10 - (s % 10);
    }

    private int sumEven(String code) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
            if (isEven(i)) {
                sum += Character.getNumericValue(code.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }


    private int sumOdd(String code) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
            if (!isEven(i)) {
                sum += Character.getNumericValue(code.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }


    private boolean isEven(int i) {
        return i % 2 == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return code;
    }
}





@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_produtos")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    public Product() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FABRICANTE")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "URL")
    private String url;

    @Embedded
    private Ean13 ean;

    @Transient
    private Keywords keywords;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCode (String code){
        ean = new Ean13(code);
    }

    public Manufacturer getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Keywords getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(Keywords keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I don't incorporate feedback. I had made changes on the orignal code and posted in an answer, but the two responses the original question receive not take into account these changes, then I decided on the original question to make it more visible.

Comment: Hi @alexpfx, you should not add code to the original question after you received reviews. Doing so would perpetuate a review. If you would like your refactorings reviewed, please ask a new question.

Comment: I understand. so I should cut these edit, close this question and open another?

Comment: @alexpfx I cleaned up this question for you. Just leave this question as-is and post a new question (this question should not be closed, and you cannot delete it as it has upvoted answers).

Comment: A word of warning for people trying to use this code for themselves, unfortunately it incorrectly validates ean 13 codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Runtime vs checked Exceptions**

As @ChristianHujer said, pre-generating exceptions is not such a good idea. The other question is if a `RuntimeException` is really the right choice to begin with.

Currently, the primary purpose of your class seems to be to hold an EAN code, and it will just fail completely - without any indication that it would - when it is passed invalid data.

This seems to be a nightmare waiting to happen, as it will be really hard for a developer to use this class correctly, and annoying to debug when it will inevitably fail.

You should always try to give the person using your code the option to recover, and if they don't know that something might go wrong, there is no way they could do that. The solution is to use checked exceptions, which you declare in the method signature, thus telling the user what can go wrong.

Of course, as @HassanAlthaf said, it might be a good idea to separate the model from the validator in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

## Don't pre-generate exceptions

On the exception in your original code: It's usually not a good idea to pre-generate exception instances. The stack trace is filled in by the constructor of `Throwable`, not by the `throw` statement, as the following code snippet demonstrates:

```
public class StackTrace {
    private static final Throwable t = new Throwable();
    public static void main(final String... args) throws Throwable {
        throw t;
    }
}
```

When you pre-generate exceptions, you will not be able to tell from the stack trace which call-tree caused the exception. In your case, you would instead see the call-tree that loaded the class:

```
$ java StackTrace 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Throwable
        at StackTrace.<clinit>(StackTrace.java:2)
```

In Java, pre-generated exceptions are usually only found in environments where the stack trace is unavailable by nature, like Java Card Classic.

## Consider converting your `String` to `int[]` first.

Normally I'd stick to Strings.
However, the case of an *EAN13* is special.
The nature of an EAN13 is to be a 13 digit code.
Converting your 13 character `String` to an `int[13]` first makes this aspect of the semantics of an EAN13 more obvious and simpler.

You could then use constants like `private static final int CHECK_DIGIT_INDEX = 12` to make it more obvious how an EAN13 is parsed. Consequently `int pretendVd = Integer.valueOf(code.substring(12, 13));` would become `int pretendVd = ean13digits[CHECK_DIGIT_INDEX];`

## Use names which are easy to understand, i.e. communicate intent

I could not find the term "pretend" resp. `pretendVd` in whatever documentation about EAN13 is available to me. I would rather call it `checkDigitFromCode`. The variable name `dv` is totally surprising, as I would at least have expected it to be `vd`. But I think `calculatedCheckDigit` or `checkDigitFromCalculation` would be better names. Even if variables have local scope, if there are multiple variables of the same type with different semantics, I'd rather be explicit about the intent of a variable and thus give it a name which communicates the intent well.
The worst name of all is `me`: The code multiplies *o*dds and then the name is `m`*`e`*.

## Method length

The method `validate(String)` is quite long, and it can be split into two methods as it performs validation on two levels. First it validates whether the code actually really is 13 digits. Second it validates whether the checksum digit of the 13 EAN13 digits is correct. So, two more methods could be extracted from `validate(String)`.

## Validation Framework

This is definitely far from mandatory, it's just food for thought and showing possibilities. If you use a persistency framework like a JPA implementation, or a dependency injection framework like Spring, or even both, or something similar, you *might* want to consider the usage of declarative validation via annotations using the `javax.validation` API.

Some people favor separating model and validation always. I wouldn't go that far, and I'll try to explain that with an exaggeration: Tomorrow they'll make 6 classes, one for the instance fields, one for the constants, one for the construction (factory), one for the validation, one for the instance methods and one for the static methods. Where should this stop? The SRP doesn't say that "Every software entity should do just one thing". It comes with a clause, and this clause is important: "Every software entity should do just one thing *on its level of abstraction*". But it also means something else: Ideally, every software entity should have just one reason to change, and a change should ideally affect only one software entity.

If the validation only changes together with the model, it might be more prudent to keep validation and model together. If the validation is to a large extent independent of the model, it might be wiser to keep them separate.

Thinking about coupling, cohesion and interfaces also helps. If the validation is so loosely coupled, i.e. decoupled from the model that it checks not a specific model but an abstract model, resp. could be reused for different similar models, it certainly should be separate. If the validation is very tightly coupled to the model, it should be more cohesive with the model. And if you insert methods in the model to interface with the validation which are only for the validation and no other user in the system, you have strong arguments for keeping the validation inside the model class.

Welcome to engineering, there's no perfect solution, it always depends... ;)

## Properly declare `static` methods.

Your methods `getEanVd(int)`, `sumEven(String)`, `sumOdd(String)` and `isEven(int)` never access any instance fields and thus could all be declared `static`.

Because they are private methods, it could actually make you wonder why you have a parameter `String code` and an instance field `String code` with identical content, which leads to:

## Consider swapping validation sequence in the constructor

I think I guess your intention of first validating, then constructing the object with the sequence `validate(code); this.code = code;` in the constructor. You do not want the object to be constructed before it's validated.

However, consider a few things.

The construction is not really completed until the constructor returns. Whether you throw an exception soon or late in the constructor doesn't matter from a black box perspective. It also doesn't matter from a performance perspective, as an exception is a bad case path, not a happy path. Usually the performance of bad case paths doesn't matter.

However, it matters from a whitebox correctness perspective. Someone might look at the methods `sumEven(String code)` and `sumOdd(String code)` and realize that they're checking the very same code which would eventually be stored in the field, and thus turn the signatures into `sumEven()` and `sumOdd()`. Compiles still fine, but breaks with `NullPointerException` because of accessing still `null` field `code` before it was assigned to a (potentially) non-`null` value in the constructor.

Therefore, given a choice, i.e. when the field initialization is as trivial as simply assigning parameters to fields, I'd initialize fields first, as that leads to more robust code: It will allow subsequent private instance methods to access the fields even when they are called from the constructor.

## Throwing the correct exceptions

The code part `if (code == null) { throw NOT_VALID_EAN_EXCEPTION; }` will be very difficult for developers to debug when it happens. Developers will assume that `code` was a `String` which was not an EAN13, but they will not expect that `code` was `null`, because the generally accepted behavior and practice is that if you pass `null` and `null` is not allowed you get nothing else but a `NullPointerException`. Getting a different exception than `NullPointerException` in case of a not-allowed `null` is very unexpected and can make developers waste a lot of debugging time staring at their code mislead into totally false assumptions.

In general, when `null` is not allowed, I'd not check, I'd simply let the code crash wherever it crashes. Whether the first check in `validate(String) throws NullPointerException` or whether some later part like `code.substring() throws NullPointerException` doesn't matter, the stack trace will always show the essential part which is that it was thrown somewhere in `validate()` called from `Ean13()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Exceptions**

Like @ChristianHujer suggested, do not pre-generate exceptions. Look at his post for details regarding this.

**The `this` keyword**

```
public Ean13(String code) {
    validate(code);
    this.code = code;
}
```

At first, in your constructor, the fact that you did not use the `this` keyword to invoke the `validate` method, looks quite weird. You should always make your code very precise. Therefore, you can replace it to:

`this.validate(code);`

That way, someone reading your code won't have a sudden stop wondering where did it come from. And then, realise, it's in the same class. The keyword `this` refers to the current class.

**Variable & Method names**

The variable names you use such as `e`, `o` are quite horrible, and do not make sense at a glance. You have to go through the code to see what they actually are. Use some meaningful variable names, do not worry about the length. A good IDE will suggest you identifier names you might be trying to refer to by just typing 2 to 3 letters and hitting enter.

You could use something like, `oddSum`, `evenSum`. That is more meaningful. Also, your method names need to improve.

**Do not make your code unnecessarily complex**

The expression: `!(pretendVd == dv)` is too complex. You could easily refactor it to: `pretendVd != dv`.

**Single Responsibility Principle**

Each class should have only responsibility. The `Ean13` class should only be responsible for representing an `Ean13` code as the name suggests, it is `Ean13`. So, what should you do? You can do something like this:

You can have a `Ean13Factory` class like this:

```
class Ean13Factory {
    public Ean13 setCode(String code) throws RuntimeException {
        // Validation, if valid, return an object or throw an exception.
    }
}
```

Your `Ean13` class should not have anything more than a `getter/setter` and a property to store the code. However, it can have some `getters/setters` accepting the code in different ways.

Also, I would recommend having a separate class for `Ean13` validation. Let's call it `Ean13Validator`.

```
class Ean13Validator {
    public void Ean13Validator(String code) throws RuntimeException {
        this.validateCode(code);
    }

    public void validateCode(String code) throws RuntimeException { .... }
}
```

Your `Product` class doesn't have any flaws other than the ones I mentioned. You need to, however, adjust your `setCode()` method in that.

So, you would do something like:

```
public void setCode(String code) {
    try {
        this.ean = Ean13Factory.setCode(code);
    } catch (RuntimeException exception) {
        this.ean = Ean13Factory.emptyInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggested `Ean13Validator` class and usage is horrible.

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely Why so?

Comment: I think omitting this where things are coming from the current class is common practice and perfectly legit.

Comment: Using the SRP - Single Responsibility Principle to argue for factory classes is an abuse of the intention of the SRP. On its level of abstraction creating instances of itself is a perfectly legit part of the responsibility of any class. If we were to follow your argument, we were to replace all non-empty constructors with factory methods in separate factory classes. Factories come into picture because of other reasons than the SRP: Polymorphic construction, or the ability to specialize construction without altering the original class.

Comment: Using short variable names can or cannot be okay. Short variable names like `e` are bad in cases where it's difficult to tell the semantics from the name. A local variable `Exception e` or `String s`, without further semantics, is legit. A local variable `int e = sumEven()` isn't legit, as two lines down I already have to wonder what `e` was. Note the difference: In `Exception e`, the `e` comes from the type, whereas in `int e`, the `e` comes from semantics `sumEven`. It's okay to abbreviate types with local scope, but abbreviating semantics in local scode obscures intent.